# Multiple Image Upload with a Single Browse

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

First of all i wanted to thank you all for ur contribution and help as much as you could.

Now i wanted to ask something, maybe is not a big deal but im not finding the way to solved it even though i have tried a lot of different ways.

So to explain in detail.. i have a **typology_pictures** table that has id|typology_id|pic_path.

when a user wants to create a new typology_picture it shows like this:

[image: Adding Images For a chosen Typology]

So the user select the typology that these pictures belonges to and when he brows, i want to allow him to select multiple image.
 and when he press submit i all image to be inserted in database each in a new row , but the **typology_id** is the same , just pic_path is different.

So the model is this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * TypologyPicture Model
 *
 * @property Typology $Typology
 */
class TypologyPicture extends AppModel {
public $name = 'TypologyPicture';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $displayField = 'typology_id';


    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'blank' => array(
                'rule' => 'blank',
                'on' => 'create',
            ),
        ),
        'typology_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                'message' => 'Chose the Typology this pic belongs to?',
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Select The typology where these picture belongs to? ',
                'on' => 'create',
            ),
        ),
        'pic_path' => array(
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'The Typology Image upload failed.',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'on' => 'create',
             ),
             'fileSize' => array(
                'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '3MB'),
                'message' => 'Cover image must be less than 3MB.',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'on' => 'create',

             ),
            'processTypologyImageUpload' => array(
                'rule' => 'processTypologyImageUpload',
                'message' => 'Unable to process cover image upload.',
                'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
             ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemTypologyPicture' => array(
            'className' => 'Typology',
            'foreignKey' => 'typology_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );


        /*CopyRight @Erland Muchasaj*/
    // This new function Doesent Upload the Picture or Image unless the Record is inserted in DB.
    public function processTypologyImageUpload($checktypology = array()) {  
        $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'typology' . DS . 'images' . DS;
            if (!isset($checktypology['pic_path']['name'])) {
                $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'You must upload a file before you Submit!');  
                return false;
            }

            if(!is_uploaded_file($checktypology['pic_path']['tmp_name'])) {
                $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'You must upload a file before you Submit!'); 
                return false; 
            } 

            if (($checktypology['pic_path']['size'] > 55000000)) {
                $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'File size is To big!');  
                return false; 
            }
                $allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif','tiff');
                $value = explode(".", $checktypology['pic_path']['name']); // Here we grab the name of the file with the extension
                $extension = strtolower(array_pop($value));   //extension
                // the file name is before the last "."
                $fileName = array_shift($value);  //Filename                        
            //$allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif','tiff');
            //$extension=strtolower(end(explode(".", $checktypology['pic_path']['name']))); 
            if(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
                $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'Invalid File Format! '); 
                return false;
            }   

            if ($checktypology['pic_path']["error"] > 0) {   
                $this->invalidate('pic_path', $checktypology['pic_path']['error']);
                return false;  
            }

            if (file_exists( WWW_ROOT . $dir) && is_dir( WWW_ROOT . $dir))  { 
                chmod(WWW_ROOT . $dir, 0777);
                if (file_exists( WWW_ROOT . $dir . $checktypology['pic_path']['name'])) { 
                    $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'File Allredy Exists!');
                    return false;     
                } 
            }

            if (!file_exists( WWW_ROOT . $dir) || !is_dir( WWW_ROOT . $dir))  { 
                mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
            }            
     // better safe then sorry!
     return true; 
    }


    // this is a Global variable that im gonna use it inside my function
        private  $image;
        public function beforeSave($options = Array()) {
            $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'typology' . DS . 'images' . DS;
            // first  we grab slider id, and we pass it's data the the variable.
            $this->image = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('TypologyPicture.id' => $this->id)));

                if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path'])) {
                    $file = $this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path'];
                        if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dir .  time() .$file['name'])) {
                            $this->invalidate('pic_path', 'File Didnt Upload! ');
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path'] = time() . $file['name'];
                return TRUE;
                }       
            return true;
        }

        public function afterSave($created, $options = Array()) {
            //$dir = 'img/uploads/typology/images/'; /*<=== DO NOT EDIT*/
            $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'typology' . DS . 'images' . DS;
            // then after deletation of the row we check if the file exist, if so we delete it. 
            if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path']) && file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $dir .  $this->image['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'])){
            chmod(WWW_ROOT . $dir, 0777);
                $img = WWW_ROOT . $dir . $this->image ['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'];
                unlink($img); 
                return true;
           } else { $this->data[$this->alias]['pic_path'] = $this->image['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'];}
           return true;
        }


        // this is a Global variable that im gonna use it inside my function
        private  $TypologyPicture;
        public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
            // first  we grab slider id, and we pass it's data the the variable.
            $this->TypologyPicture = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('TypologyPicture.id' => $this->id)));
            return true;
        }

         public function afterDelete() {
         //$dir = 'img/uploads/typology/images/'; /*<=== DO NOT EDIT*/
         $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'typology' . DS . 'images' . DS;
         // then after deletation of the row we check if the file exist, if so we delete it. 
            if(file_exists(WWW_ROOT . $dir .  $this->TypologyPicture['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'])){
            chmod(WWW_ROOT . $dir, 0777);
                $img = WWW_ROOT . $dir . $this->TypologyPicture ['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'];
                unlink($img); 
                return true;
           }
           return true;
        } 


}
```

**Controller for the Add action:**

```
public function add() {
    $this->layout='typology_add';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {       
         if (!empty($this->data)) {

            $this->TypologyPicture->create();
            if(empty($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']['name'])){
                unset($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']);
              }
            if ($this->TypologyPicture->saveAll($this->data)) 
            {        
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else 
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            } // END OF TypologyPicture->save


       } // END OF THE !empty();    
     if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->TypologyPicture->read(null, $id);
        }        
    }


        $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('typologies'));
}
```

**And the view is this:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('TypologyPicture', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Typology Pictures'); ?></legend>
  <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('typology_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('pic_path', array('label'=>'Picture','type'=>'file'));
  ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

i Would really apruciate your help.

Thanx!

**EDIT:**

This is the code i have writen so far!

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {       
        $dir = 'img' . DS . 'uploads' . DS . 'typology' . DS . 'images' . DS;
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']['name']);$i++){
            if(empty($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['name'])) {
                unset($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['name']);
            }
            if(!empty($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['tmp_name'])){    
                $allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif','tiff');
                $value = explode(".", $this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['name']); // Here we grab the name of the file with the extension
                $extension = strtolower(array_pop($value));   //extension
                if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
                    if ($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['error'] <= 0) { 
                        chmod(WWW_ROOT . $dir, 0777); 
                        move_uploaded_file($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dir  . mktime().$this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['name']);
                        $this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'] = mktime().$this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path'][$i]['name'];
                    }
                }
            } 
            $this->TypologyPicture->create();
            if ($this->TypologyPicture->save($this->data)){        
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            } // END OF ItemPicture->save
        }
    }        
    $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('typologies'));
}
```

I also changed the input field to:

```
echo $this->Form->input('pic_path.', array('label'=>'Picture','multiple'=>'multiple' ,'type'=>'file'));
```

in order to support multifile select. but again nothing seems to be working..

I just get a :

The request has been black-holed    Error: The requested address '/cesifull/typology_pictures/add' was not found on this server.

Any Suggestion... anyone!

Answer (score 0):

Being able to select multiple files through a single file input is an HTML5 feature, so any solution you write will most likely involve HTML5.  If you do not want to use HTML5, people have made Flash and Java plugins for multiple image uploading as well.

http://verens.com/2009/12/28/multiple-file-uploads-using-html5/

Comment: As long as i am aware of, cakephp uses HTML5 so i think it supports multifile uploads

Comment: It's more a question of what browsers you want to support, since many browsers do not support HTML5 features, like older versions of of IE.  If that's not a concern, then HTML5 multiple file input is the easy way to do it.

Comment: well i want that main browsers to do so, like google chrome and FireFox. If you know a way how to do it @Kai , it would be a big help indeed...

Comment: See the link I posted in my answer.  The main thing is that you want to use the attribute multiple="multiple" in your file input, so it will use the multiple file input, and then you need to change your add action to work properly with receiving an array of files.

Comment: I did change the atribute to `multiple` as you may see to the edit question. i also added the modified function as well but it seems its not workin @Kai :/. I don't know what i am doing wrong or what i'm missing...